# Is it possible to translate everething written in OCaml to PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, translation, ocaml

Is it possible to translate everething written in OCaml to PHP? for example will it be hard to translate such lib as lib for [Fast content-aware image resizing](http://eigenclass.org/hiki/seam-carving-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, long answer yes, but it might be difficult.  In this particular case the author translated code from Python ([code found here](http://blog.eikke.com/index.php/ikke/2007/09/02/seam_carving_content_aware_image_resizin)) into OCaml.  Additionally you can read the paper that presents the algorithm [here (pdf link).](http://www.shaiavidan.org/papers/imretFinal.pdf)  Given that you have two implementations and access to the paper describing the algorithm I'd say guess that it won't be difficult to implement in PHP.

That said, OCaml is a compiled language and will run a lot faster than PHP.  The Python implementation uses a lot of C libraries to speed it up (and is still half as fast as the OCaml implementation).